# Display to two divs inline side by side

Tags: html, css

I am trying to stuck two divs side by side using `inline-block`.

However for some reason it won't just work. With this I have two questions:

1. How can I display inline block side by side the `<nav>` and the `<article>` container. The nav will be floated on left while the article will be floated on the right. Again how can I use `display: inline-block` with this. I don't need a `float`.
2. How can I change list style of the ul li ul li and fix their position that are indented like this: http://prntscr.com/7koc47

Here's my CSS:

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}


/* General CSS */

body{
 background-color: #eeeeee;
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
 font-size: 17px;
}

#wrapper{
 width: 970px;
 margin: 0 auto;

}


header{
 background-color: #dddddd;
 padding: 15px;
 margin: 15px 0;
}

header h1{
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

nav{
 background-color: #dddddd;

}

nav{
 display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li{
 list-style: disc;
}

nav ul > li{
 list-style: circle;
}

nav ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
}



article{
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #aaaaaa;
 margin: 20px 0;
}


article h2{
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 20px 0;
}


article ul li{
 list-style: disc;
 margin: 15px 0;
}

article ul li a{
 font-weight: bold;

}

footer{
 background-color: #dddddd;
 margin: 15px 0;
}

.border{
 -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
 -moz-border-radius: 25px;
 border-radius: 25px;
 padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

<header class="border">
<h1>@ Loup's</h1>
</header>

<nav id="links" class="border">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        <ul> 
        <li><a href="#">articles/</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">beliefs respect and facts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">classes suck</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">taboo oo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">classes as syntatic sugar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">syntatic sugar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">better keyboards</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ideal computer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">assignment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">language</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dcvs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">is fp feasible</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">does oo sucks</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    

        <li><a href="#">projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">tutorials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact me</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>  

<article class="border">
<h2>My essays</h2>
<p>My last posts depend on each other, and should be read in sequence. Articles not in bold are optionnal.</p>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Assignment Statement Considered Harmfull</a>. Pervasive mutable state mate programs more difficult to deal with. While this is old news, most programmers don't know or don't care. It's a pitty, because <a href="#">simple remedies</a> exist.</li>

    <li><a href="#">Defining Syntatic Sugar</a>. I sometimes hear arguments about what is or is not syntactic sugar. This is an attempt at defining it. </li>

    <li><a href="#">Class-based Programming as Syntactic Sugar</a>. Most of the time, "Object Oriented" actually mean classes. Classes are nothing more than syntactic sugar, at least in statically typed languages such as Java and C++. Sugar is not useless, but seeing past it helps us understand classes better.</li>

    <li><a href="#">Taboo "OO"</a>. The term "OO" is so overloaded that we should stop using it. Better substitutes are "classes" and "prototypes".</li>


    <li><a href="#">How Class based Programming Sucks</a>. Classes are vastly sub-optimal. Functional programming is far better.</li>
</ul>
</article>


<footer class="border">
    <p>Contact, suggestions: Send me an email at <a href="#">l@loup-valliant.fr</a></p>
    <p>Built with <a href="#">USSM</a></p>
</footer>
```

Check my JSFIDDLE here: https://jsfiddle.net/yshckr8a/

Comment: applying width to both containers i.e. nav & article should resolve this issue

Comment: On a side note, the * css selector can be used for any element. Maybe it's just me but that first selector seems huge.

Comment: give them widths that will add up to less than the wrapper width less than the (minus horizontal margins and padding) and comment out the white space in between them (otherwise you get a space like you would in a sentence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your CSS:

```
nav{
    display: inline-block;
}
nav ul:first-child > li:first-child {
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul:first-child > li:first-child > a{
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    list-style: disc !important;
}

nav ul ul > li{
    list-style: circle !important;
    padding-left: 10px;
}


nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To display your article next to your nav, you just need to set a width to your article :

```
article {
   width: 70%;
}
```

To move the sub ul li, just add a margin on it :

```
#links > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

For your list style:

```
#links > ul > li > ul > li {
  list-style-type: initial;
}
#links > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
  list-style: outside none circle;
}
#links > ul > li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

UPDATED JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/yshckr8a/3/

Comment: You might want to use a direct child selector to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

## 1.

The reason that the two `div's` are not align side by side, is that they don't have enough space, for proof you can add `width` to the article
and make both of the `div's` vertically aligned to top.

I'd suggest that you use percentages if possible for the `article` and `nav`

```
nav {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 20%;
}

article { 
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 69%;
}
```

## 2.

For the second problem just add `margin-left` to the `ul` class

```
ul { 
    margin-left: 10px
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yshckr8a/2/)